# Validate user registration with firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

I am new to Firebase. I have a custom subscription page with email and password.

In the webApp I am working on, I would like to send an activation email every time someone subscribes. However, I would like this email to be sent to **an administrator** instead of being sent to the user itself.

I do not want the users to activate their accounts, but an administrator, who does not know anything about programming.

Is there an easy way with firebase to do such a thing?

Thank you!

PS: I am using firebase with ReactJS, if this helps :-)

Comment: You'll probably need to use a cloud function along with a third-party email delivery provider. The cloud function can be triggered when a new user signs up and then have whatever custom logic you want to deliver the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase has an example of sending emails through Gmail. Please see the link. You can store and read the administrator email address in the firebase db. In the email to the administrator, you direct the admin to click the link to your webapp to activate the user.

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/email-users/functions/index.js